# Tomcat java servlet - how to track users that are logged in?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, tracking

I am going to create a simple player versus player servlet-based browser game and deploy it in tomcat, and I need to be able to know at any given point in time which users are connected. Each user will have his own account (username, password, role) that will be stored in a mysql database (using a jdbc realm). What I want to do is to somehow track all users by having a database table where usernames of logged on users are stored.

The only problem is how do I know when someone logs in or out.

**Edit: I saw someone recommending a HttpSessionBindingListener in another post. However, I have not got the slightest idea on how to implement this**

Comment: Are you going to use plain servlets or any framework (like Spring)?

Comment: Plain servlets preferably.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to track this is to log all the *events*, user login and user logout, and store this with a time stamp. This makes it much easier to implement timeout and other features.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that?

Comment: Create a schema for this (a separate table is likely the best). Every time someone logs in or out you write a record to that table.

Comment: OK. Maybe I did not phrase the question correctly. How do I know when someone logs in or out?

Answer (score 0):

you can use log4j framework for your project logging. 
you can find implementation at this site
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm